# Though deprecated, shouldn't body-parser still work?

Tags: node.js, express, server, newsletter

Though body-parser has been deprecated, it should still work.

```
 const express = require("express");
 const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
 const request = require("request");
 const https = require("https");

 const app = express(); //this is a new instance of express

 app.use(express.static("public"));

 app.use(bodyParser, urlencoded({ extended: true }));

 app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");
});
```

Console output using body-parser

```
    [app crash error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkLVH.png)
```

And my code with body-parser commented out...

```
    const express = require("express");
    //const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    const request = require("request");
    const https = require("https");

    const app = express(); //this is a new instance of express

    app.use(express.static("public"));
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    //app.use(bodyParser, urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    app.get("/", function (req, res) {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");
    });
```

This works and my app doesn't crash

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the docs on how to use body-parser. https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```